Powershell script as SYSTEM : ArgumentOutOfRangeException
I try to launch directory-treesize.ps1 (https://github.com/jagilber/powershellScripts/blob/master/directory-treesize.ps1) as SYSTEM user.
I get this error :
 +     [dotNet]::Start($directory, $minSizeGB, $depth, [bool]$showFiles, ...
 +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException

As other user, it works.
Here is full command line i use :
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file "C:\scripts\directory-treesize.ps1" -depth 5 -directory "D:\"
-minSizeGB 30 -notree -noColor -logFile "c:\scripts\details.txt"

Can you help me or explain why i can't launch this script as SYSTEM?
Thanks.
EDIT
On windows 10 and server 2012 R2, it is working well. On 2022 not. Powershell version 5.1.
Tested with PS7 on 2022. Same error.

I think it is related to Differences between Windows PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell 7.x

Powershell version is 5.1. Shall i update to v7?

I cannot advice you in this.  (But when you do this seems to work)

I do not understand, it is not recommended to update to PS7? ^^

Powershell5 is still standard installed/used/provided with Windows. I simply said I cannot advise you anything. (You have to decide yourself if your install it or not). But these versions (5 and 7.x) live side by side, so no harm should be done when you install it.
